# Unblock From GetQueuedCompletionStatus

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, winsock2, resource-cleanup

During program termination, how do you unblock a thread that has been previously blocked with a call to `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()`?

Comment: you can also utilize the builtin windows threadpool which comes with internal IOCP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could post termination message to the IO completion port using `PostQueuedCompletionStatus` API call or simply close `IOCP` handle using `CloseHandle`.

> If a call to `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` fails because the completion
>   port handle associated with it is closed while the call is
>   outstanding, the function returns `FALSE`, `*lpOverlapped` will be
>   `NULL`, and `GetLastError` will return `ERROR_ABANDONED_WAIT_0`.

Comment: Thank you very much! `CloseHandle` and handling `ERROR_ABANDONED_WAIT_0` sounds like the perfect route. I appreciate your time.